# Slow response when the HTML table is big

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I am using JavaScript to generate a HTML table of 4 columns, but when the table became very large (e.g. more than 1000 rows), the user could face lag between their interaction (e.g. hovering on a row, scrolling, or clicking something) and the response of the webpage.

This is the demo to show my issue, please run it on fullscreen, you can notice (or not noticing it if your computer is fast enough...) a small lag of hover effect when you move your mouse quickly between rows:

```js
/**
 * @namespace Start the project called 'stck'
 */
var stck = {};

/**
 * Variable to save stock loaded
 */
stck.stockInfo = [];

/**
 * Load the item informaction acording the SKU
 * @private
 * @param {string} SKU The SKU of the item
 */
stck.loadItemInformation = function(SKU) {
  var descriptionsTable = document.getElementById('descriptionsTable');
  for (var rowsLength = descriptionsTable.rows.length - 1; --rowsLength; ) {
    descriptionsTable.deleteRow(1);
  }
  var pricesTable = document.getElementById('pricesTable');
  for (var rowsLength = pricesTable.rows.length - 1; --rowsLength; ) {
    pricesTable.deleteRow(1);
  }
  document.getElementById('tableHeader').style.cssText = '';
  document.getElementById('tableContent').style.cssText = '';

  // Load data with AJAX and process here
  document.getElementById('addItemButton').className = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('saveButton').className = document.getElementById('cancelButton').className = '';
  document.getElementById('tables').className = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('editItem').className = 'active';
};

/**
 * Show row to the 'tableContent' table.
 * @public
 * @param {number} showQuantity The quantity that will be loaded
 * @param {boolean} isLoadNewStock Define if the quantity that are going to be show are lower than stock, will load new stock information or not
 */
stck.showRow = function(showQuantity, isLoadNewStock) {
  var stock = stck.stockInfo;
  var tableContent = document.getElementById('tableContent');
  var tableContentRowsLength = tableContent.rows.length;
  var stockInfoLength = stck.stockInfo.length;
  var toIndex = tableContentRowsLength + showQuantity;
  if (toIndex > stockInfoLength) {
    if (isLoadNewStock && stck.loadStock(10, true, false)) {
      return;
    } else {
      toIndex = stockInfoLength;
    }
  }
  for (var i = tableContentRowsLength, row, rowNumber, cellIndex, SKUCell, descriptionCell, stockCell, clickHandler; i < toIndex; ++i) {
    row = tableContent.insertRow(i);
    rowNumber = document.createElement('TH');
    rowNumber.innerText = i + 1;
    row.appendChild(rowNumber);
    cellIndex = 0;
    SKUCell = row.insertCell(++cellIndex);
    SKUCell.innerHTML = stock[i][0];
    descriptionCell = row.insertCell(++cellIndex);
    descriptionCell.innerHTML = stock[i][1];
    stockCell = row.insertCell(++cellIndex);
    stockCell.className = 'stock';
    stockCell.innerHTML = stock[i][2];
    clickHandler = function(row) {
      return function() {
        stck.loadItemInformation(stock[row][0]);
      };
    };
    row.onclick = clickHandler(i);
  }
};

/**
 * This code is for test
 */
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  stck.stockInfo.push(['TESTSKU', 'A test item', i]);
}
stck.showRow(10000, false)
```

```css
html{height:100%;background-color:#FFF;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#EEE),to(#FFF));background:-webkit-radial-gradient(#FFF,#FFF 35%,#EEE);background:-moz-radial-gradient(#FFF,#FFF 35%,#EEE);background:radial-gradient(#FFF,#FFF 35%,#EEE);-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:-moz-none;-o-user-select:none;user-select:none;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;cursor:default}
::-moz-selection,::selection{background:transparent}
::-moz-focus-inner{border:none}
body{margin:0;background-color:transparent;overflow:hidden}
body,th,td,input,textarea{color:#333;font:13px/1.2 Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;-webkit-border-radius:0;text-rendering:optimizelegibility}
a{outline:none}
img{border:none;behavior:url(/i/iepngfix.htc)}
table{border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse}
article,aside,hgroup,footer,header,nav,section{display:block}

input,select{margin:2px 0;padding:3px;-webkit-border-radius:0;-webkit-box-shadow:none;-webkit-appearance:none;border:1px solid #B8ADA5;overflow:visible}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{display:none}
input:hover,select:hover{border-color:#4A0}
input:focus,select:focus{border-color:#4A0;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #4A0;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px #4A0;box-shadow:0 0 3px #4A0;outline:none}
input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}
.b{clear:both;margin-top:10px;padding:0 4px;border-top:1px dashed #CCC;text-align:right}
.b input{width:auto;min-width:54px;height:29px;margin:6px 0 6px 6px;padding:0 8px;border:1px solid #3079ED;-webkit-border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;background-color:#4D90FE;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4D90FE),to(#4787ED));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);color:#FFF;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;line-height:27px;-webkit-transition:0.1s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:0.1s ease-in-out;-o-transition:0.1s ease-in-out;transition:0.1s ease-in-out;text-align:center;cursor:pointer}
.b input:hover{background-color:#357AE8;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4D90FE),to(#357AE8));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#357AE8);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#357AE8);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#357AE8)}
.b input:active,.b input:focus{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);outline:none}
input:disabled,textarea:disabled{color:#999;cursor:not-allowed}
textarea:disabled::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#F9F9F9}
.b input:disabled{color:#EEE;cursor:not-allowed}
.b input:disabled:hover{background-color:#4D90FE;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4D90FE),to(#4787ED));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);-webkit-box-shadow:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none}

#gpanel{position:fixed;top:0;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;height:43px;padding:0 5px;-moz-border-radius:0 1px;border-bottom:1px solid #000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.85);line-height:46px;-webkit-transition:.1s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:.1s ease-in-out;-o-transition:0.1s ease-in-out;transition:.1s ease-in-out;overflow:hidden;z-index:10}
#gpanel.hidden{top:-44px}
#gpanel ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}
#gpanel li{float:left;overflow:hidden}
#gpanel a{display:block;padding:0 10px;color:#DDD;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;cursor:pointer;-webkit-transition:.1s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:.1s ease-in-out;-o-transition:0.1s ease-in-out;transition:.1s ease-in-out}
#gpanel a:hover{background-color:rgba(204,204,204,.4);color:#FFF}
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  0% {background-color:rgba(204,204,204,.4)}
  50% {background-color:rgba(119,187,68,.9)}
  100% {background-color:rgba(204,204,204,.4)}
}
@-moz-keyframes loading {
  0% {background-color:rgba(204,204,204,.4)}
  50% {background-color:rgba(119,187,68,.9)}
  100% {background-color:rgba(204,204,204,.4)}
}
#gpanel a:active,#gpanel a:focus{background-color:rgba(119,187,68,.9);-webkit-animation:loading .5s infinite linear;-moz-animation:loading .5s infinite linear}
#gnav{float:left;overflow:hidden}
#gmanager{float:right;margin-right:4px}

#body{margin-top:44px;overflow:auto}

#overlay{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;background-color:rgba(127,127,127,0.5);background:-webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(127,127,127,.5),rgba(127,127,127,.5) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,.7));background:-moz-radial-gradient(rgba(127,127,127,.5),rgba(127,127,127,.5) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,.7));-webkit-transition:opacity .25s linear;-moz-transition:opacity .25s linear;transition:opacity .25s linear;opacity:1;overflow-y:auto;z-index:15}
#overlay.hidden{opacity:0;visibility:hidden}
#overlay .hidden{display:none}
#overlay form{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;border:1px solid #BCC1D0;-webkit-border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 5px 80px #505050;-moz-box-shadow:0px 5px 80px #505050;background:#FFF url(../image/lightbox.png) bottom repeat-x;text-align:left}.window p{margin:5px 0}.window label{display:block;text-transform:uppercase;font:700 10px Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;zoom:1}.window input[type="text"],.window input[type="number"],.window input[type="password"],.window textarea{padding:2px;border:1px solid;border-color:#999 #333 #333 #999;background:#FFF}.window table{margin:0;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse}.window th,.window td{border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;background:none}.window select{width:65px}#code,#desc,#desc_cn,#password,#largedescription{width:350px}#price{width:100px}.window input[type="submit"]{padding:5px 10px;border:1px solid;border-color:#FC0 #F60 #F60 #FC0;background:#F90}.window input[type="reset"]{padding:5px 10px;border:1px solid;border-color:#EEE #333 #333 #EEE;background:#CCC}
#overlay h1,#body h1{margin:0;padding:10px 20px 5px;border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;color:#848589;font:400 30px 'Segoe UI',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}
#overlay h1{font-size:24px}
#overlay .contentArea{padding:10px 15px 5px}
#overlay label{font-weight:700}
form#addItemPage{width:500px;margin:-126px 0 0 -251px}
#addItemPage .contentArea p{overflow:auto}
#addItemPage .contentArea label{display:block;width:470px;line-height:28px}
#addItemPage .contentArea input{float:right;width:330px;margin-right:3px}

#body h1{height:41px}
#stock a{color:#FFF;background-color:#7B4}
#functions{padding:13px 10px;float:right}
#functions ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}
#functions li{display:inline-block;min-width:54px;height:27px;margin-left:6px;padding:0 8px;border:1px solid #3079ED;-webkit-border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;background:#4D90FE;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4D90FE),to(#4787ED));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#4787ED);color:#FFF;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;line-height:27px;cursor:pointer}
#functions li:hover{background:#357AE8;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4D90FE),to(#357AE8));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#357AE8);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#357AE8);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4D90FE,#357AE8)}
#functions li:active,#functions li:focus{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);outline:none}
#functions li.hidden{display:none}

#tables{position:absolute;top:101px;bottom:0;width:100%;-webkit-transition:.3s linear;-moz-transition:.3s linear;transition:.3s linear;overflow-y:scroll}
#tables.hidden{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale(0);-moz-transform:scale(0);-o-transform:scale(0);-ms-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0)}
#tables:focus{outline:none}
::-moz-focus-inner{border:none}
#tables table{width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}
#tableHeader{top:101px}
.indexCol{width:50px}
.SKUCol{width:115px}
.brandCol{width:105px}
.stockCol{width:85px}
tr#noItem{text-align:center;cursor:default}
tr#noItem:hover{background:#FFF}
.stock{text-align:right}
#tables th,#tables td{padding:9px 6px;white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden}
#tables thead th{border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;background-color:#F5F5F5;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#F5F5F5,#F1F1F1);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#F5F5F5,#F1F1F1);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#F5F5F5,#F1F1F1);font-weight:700;cursor:default}
#tables tbody th{font-weight:700;text-overflow:none}
#tables tbody tr{background:#FFF;cursor:pointer}
#tables tbody tr:nth-child(even){background:#F8F9FC}
#tables tbody tr:hover{background:#CDE}

#editItem{position:fixed;top:101px;bottom:0;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;padding:0 20px;visibility:hidden;opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale(2);-moz-transform:scale(2);-o-transform:scale(2);-ms-transform:scale(2);transform:scale(2);-webkit-transition:.3s linear;-moz-transition:.3s linear;-o-transition:.3s linear;transition:.3s linear}
#editItem.active{visibility:visible;opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scale(1);-moz-transform:scale(1);-o-transform:scale(1);-ms-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}
#editItem header{height:51px;overflow:auto}
#editItem h2{float:left;margin:0 20px 0 0;padding:10px 0;color:#7B4;font:400 20px 'Seoge UI',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}
#editItem ul{list-style:none;margin:10px 0;padding:0;border-bottom:1px solid #7B4}
#editItem li{display:inline-block;margin:0 5px;padding:8px 10px 7px;color:#7B4;cursor:pointer;text-transform:uppercase;-webkit-transition:.15s linear;-moz-transition:.15s linear;transition:.15s linear}
#editItem li:hover{background:rgba(204,204,204,.4);color:#000}
#editItem li.active{background-color:#7B4;color:#FFF;font-weight:700;cursor:default}
#editItem .container{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;height:100%;overflow:hidden}
#editItem .tabs{position:relative;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;height:100%;-webkit-transition:.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition:.5s ease-in-out;transition:.5s ease-in-out}
#editItem section{width:100%;height:100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;overflow-y:auto}
#editItem section div{float:left;width:50%;padding:5px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#editItem label{float:left;width:20%;min-width:50px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#editItem table{width:100%;table-layout:fixed}
#descriptionsTable{margin-top:5px;border-top:1px solid #DDD}
#editItem th{font-weight:700;text-align:left}
#editItem th, #editItem td{padding:5px 2px}
#editItem img{display:block;margin:0 auto;opacity:.5;cursor:pointer}
#editItem tr:hover img{opacity:1}
#inputsTable .labelCol{width:100px}
#inputsTable label{float:none;display:block;width:100%;height:100%}
#editItem input, #editItem select{width:100%;height:26px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#editItem .languageCol{width:190px}
#editItem .deleteCol{width:25px}
#editItem #statusInput{width:auto;height:auto;margin:4px 4px 4px 0;-webkit-appearance:checkbox}
#editItem label[for="statusInput"]{display:inline;width:auto;height:auto}
#editItem textarea{box-sizing:border-box;width:100%}
#newDescriptionRow select{visibility:hidden}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/s/master.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/s/stock.css">
<title>Existencia | HDX</title>
<body>
<header id="gheader"><nav id="gpanel"><ul id="gnav"><li id="stock"><a href="/76091132/existencia/">Existencia</a></ul><ul id="gmanager">
<li id="user"><a href="/76091132/">Tester</a>
<li id="exit"><a href="/76091132/salir">Salir</a>
</ul>
</nav>
</header><div id="overlay" class="hidden">
<form id="addItemPage" class="hidden">
<h1>Agregar un artículo</h1>
<div class="contentArea">
<p><label>SKU<input type="text" id="newSKUInput" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off"></label>
<p><label>Descripción<input type="text" id="newDescriptionInput" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off"></label>
<p><label>Precio unitario<input type="number" id="newUnitPriceInput" min="1" value="1" autocomplete="off"></label>
</div>
<div class="b">
<input type="submit" value="Agregar"><input type="reset" value="Cancelar">
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="body"><header>
<div id="functions">
<ul>
<li id="addItemButton">Agregar un artículo
<li id="cancelButton" class="hidden">Cancelar
<li id="saveButton" class="hidden">Guardar
</ul>
</div>
<h1 class="fn">Existencia</h1>
</header>
<div id="tables" tabindex="0">
<table id="tableHeader">
<colgroup>
<col class="indexCol">
<col class="SKUCol">
<col>
<col class="stockCol">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr><th>#<th>SKU<th>Descripción<th>Existencia
</thead>
</table>
<table id="tableContent">
<colgroup>
<col class="indexCol">
<col class="SKUCol">
<col>
<col class="stockCol">
</colgroup>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>

<div id="editItem">
<header>
<h2>Editar artículo</h2>
<nav>
<ul id="tabsLabels">
<li id="generalTabButton" class="active">General
<li id="stockTabButton">Existencia
<li id="facturationTabButton">Facturación
<li id="optionsTabButton">Opciones
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<div id="tabsContainer" class="container">
<div id="tabsContents" class="tabs">
<section id="generalTab">
<div>
<table id="inputsTable">
<colgroup>
<col class="labelCol">
</colgroup>
<tr><th><label for="SKUInput">SKU</label><td><input type="text" id="SKUInput" autocomplete="off">
</table>
<table id="descriptionsTable">
<colgroup><col><col class="languageCol"><col class="deleteCol"></colgroup>
<tr><th>Descripción<th>Idioma<th>
<tr id="newDescriptionRow"><td><input type="text" id="descriptionInput" placeholder="Escriba aquí para una descripción nueva en otro idioma" autocomplete="off"><td><select id="languageSelect"><option value="aa">afar<option value="ab">abjaso<option value="ae">avéstico<option value="af">afrikaans<option value="ak">akano<option value="am">amárico<option value="an">aragonés<option value="ar">árabe<option value="as">asamés<option value="av">avar<option value="ay">aimara<option value="az">azerí<option value="ba">baskir<option value="be">bielorruso<option value="bg">búlgaro<option value="bh">bhojpurí<option value="bi">bislama<option value="bm">bambara<option value="bn">bengalí<option value="bo">tibetano<option value="br">bretón<option value="bs">bosnio<option value="ca">catalán<option value="ce">checheno<option value="ch">chamorro<option value="cn">chino<option value="co">corso<option value="cr">cree<option value="cs">checo<option value="cu">eslavo eclesiástico antiguo<option value="cv">chuvasio<option value="cy">galés<option value="da">danés<option value="de">alemán<option value="dv">maldivo<option value="dz">dzongkha<option value="ee">ewe<option value="el">griego<option value="en">inglés<option value="eo">esperanto<option value="es">español<option value="et">estonio<option value="eu">euskera<option value="fa">persa<option value="ff">fula<option value="fi">finés<option value="fj">fiyiano<option value="fo">feroés<option value="fr">francés<option value="fy">frisón<option value="ga">irlandés<option value="gd">gaélico escocés<option value="gl">gallego<option value="gn">guaraní<option value="gu">guyaratí<option value="gv">manés<option value="ha">hausa<option value="he">hebreo<option value="hi">hindi<option value="ho">hiri motu<option value="hr">croata<option value="ht">haitiano<option value="hu">húngaro<option value="hy">armenio<option value="hz">herero<option value="ia">interlingua<option value="id">indonesio<option value="ie">occidental<option value="ig">igbo<option value="ii">yi de Sichuán<option value="ik">inupiaq<option value="io">ido<option value="is">islandés<option value="it">italiano<option value="iu">inuktitut<option value="ja">japonés<option value="jv">javanés<option value="ka">georgiano<option value="kg">kongo<option value="ki">kikuyu<option value="kj">kuanyama<option value="kk">kazajo<option value="kl">groenlandés<option value="km">camboyano<option value="kn">canarés<option value="ko">coreano<option value="kr">kanuri<option value="ks">cachemiro<option value="ku">kurdo<option value="kv">komi<option value="kw">córnico<option value="ky">kirguís<option value="la">latín<option value="lb">luxemburgués<option value="lg">luganda<option value="li">limburgués<option value="ln">lingala<option value="lo">lao<option value="lt">lituano<option value="lu">luba-katanga<option value="lv">letón<option value="mg">malgache<option value="mh">marshalés<option value="mi">maorí<option value="mk">macedonio<option value="ml">malayalam<option value="mn">mongol<option value="mr">maratí<option value="ms">malayo<option value="mt">maltés<option value="my">birmano<option value="na">nauruano<option value="nb">noruego bokmål<option value="nd">ndebele del norte<option value="ne">nepalí<option value="ng">ndonga<option value="nl">neerlandés<option value="nn">nynorsk<option value="no">noruego<option value="nr">ndebele del sur<option value="nv">navajo<option value="ny">chichewa<option value="oc">occitano<option value="oj">ojibwa<option value="om">oromo<option value="or">oriya<option value="os">osético<option value="pa">panyabí<option value="pi">pali<option value="pl">polaco<option value="ps">pastú<option value="pt">portugués<option value="qu">quechua<option value="rm">retorrománico<option value="rn">kirundi<option value="ro">rumano<option value="ru">ruso<option value="rw">ruandés<option value="sa">sánscrito<option value="sc">sardo<option value="sd">sindhi<option value="se">sami septentrional<option value="sg">sango<option value="sh">serbocroata<option value="si">cingalés<option value="sk">eslovaco<option value="sl">esloveno<option value="sm">samoano<option value="sn">shona<option value="so">somalí<option value="sq">albanés<option value="sr">serbio<option value="ss">suazi<option value="st">sesotho<option value="su">sundanés<option value="sv">sueco<option value="sw">suajili<option value="ta">tamil<option value="te">telugú<option value="tg">tayiko<option value="th">tailandés<option value="ti">tigriña<option value="tk">turcomano<option value="tl">tagalo<option value="tn">setsuana<option value="to">tongano<option value="tr">turco<option value="ts">tsonga<option value="tt">tártaro<option value="tw">twi<option value="ty">tahitiano<option value="ug">uigur<option value="uk">ucraniano<option value="ur">urdu<option value="uz">uzbeko<option value="ve">venda<option value="vi">vietnamita<option value="vo">volapük<option value="wa">valón<option value="wl">walisiano<option value="wo">wolof<option value="xh">xhosa<option value="yi">yídish<option value="yo">yoruba<option value="za">chuan<option value="zh">chino<option value="zu">zulú</select><td>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table id="inputsTable">
<colgroup>
<col class="labelCol">
</colgroup>
<tr><th>Estado<td><input type="checkbox" id="statusInput" value="1"><label for="statusInput">Activo</label>
<!--<tr><th><label for="departmentSelect">Departamento</label><td><select></select>
<tr><th><label for="categorySelect">Categoría</label><td><select></select>
<tr><th><label for="noteTextArea">Notas</label><td><textarea></textarea>-->
</table>
</div>
</section>
<section id="stockTab">
<div>
<table id="stadisticTable">
<tr><th>Inventario<td>0
<tr><th>Cantidad vendido<td>0
<tr><th>Última fecha de modificación<td>
</table>
</div>
</section>
<section id="facturationTab">
<div>
<table id="pricesTable">
<colgroup><col><col><col><col><col class="deleteCol"></colgroup>
<tr><th>Código<th>Unidad<th>Cantidad equivalente<th>Precio<th>
<tr id="newPriceRow"><td><input type="text" id="codeInput" autocomplete="off"><td><input type="text" id="unitInput" autocomplete="off"><td><input type="text" id="quantityInput" autocomplete="off"><td><input type="text" id="priceInput" autocomplete="off"><td>
</table>
</div>
</section>
<section id="optionsTab">
<p>Imprimir precio
</section>
</div></div>
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: 1,000 rows doesn't seem all that many. Are you saying it performs fine if you remove the `tr:hover` effect?

Comment: pagination man! why load 1000 rows?

Comment: Are you sure it's due to some inefficiencies in the front-end stack? Not when e.g. you loaded the data from the DB?

Comment: You should be careful when adding javascript to the page scroll event as it'll get fired very often and slow down the whole page, especially when it's 1,000 items long.

Comment: Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/bBBtq/. Is it slow for you? It's 1000 rows with `tr:hover` and it works fine for me. I upped it to 10,000 rows and saw no difference. Something else on your page is probably the slow down, not the row count. I would resolve whatever that is before resorting to AJAX and scrolling hacks.

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com I'm sure, because the data is already loaded.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Well, your demo is not slow for me. I updated the post including my CSS code that work with the table.

Comment: I'd guess that there may be some events bound without event delegation.

Comment: Have you taken the `tr:hover` out of the css to see if the page speeds up?

Comment: I updated the demo with all your CSS. It's still not slow. Post some of your Javascript related to this `table`.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Your demo is not slow for me. I updated the post and added a demo link in the final, you can check it.. The demo I posted is very slow for me...

Comment: I suppose some people are taking the approach of just limiting how many rows render. For me, rendering, say, 300 or fewer rows is basically instantaneous, so I create an illusion of availability via scrolling events and filtering events and it works quite well, where before, my 1400 or so rows would take about 6 seconds to render.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first thing that is slowing your loop down is `.insertRow()`. You're doing this at the top of your loop and then adding cells to it. After the row is added, and after each cell is added, the browser is doing layout calculations. Instead use `.createElement()` and then `.appendChild()` at the end of your loop.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/gyaGk/

Replace:

```
row = tableContent.insertRow(i);
```

With:

```
row = document.createElement('tr');
```

And add this at the end of your loop:

```
tableContent.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);
```

That will solve your loading speed issue. As for the hover, you have way too many CSS rules affecting your `tr` and `td` elements using tag selectors. I removed a few, and used classes on a few, and the hover highlighting is much faster. Specifically, I noticed that `overflow: hidden` on the `td` elements slowed it down considerably. Consider combining some of your rules, using simpler selectors, and adding classes to elements for quicker CSS processing. During hover many things have to be recalculated by the the layout engine, and the fewer CSS rules the better. One example I saw in your code was `#tables tbody tr` when there was only one `tbody` in the table. `#tables tr` would have sufficed. Better than either of those is a class. I used `.row` in my demo.

Best practices from [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors):

- Avoid descendant selectors: `table tbody tr td`
- Avoid redundant ancestors: `body section article` (`body` never needed)
- Avoid universal (*) selectors: `body *`
- Avoid tag selectors as the key (right-most): `ul li`
- Avoid child or adjacent selectors: `ul > li > a`
- Avoid overly qualified selectors: `form#UserLogin` (`#` is already specific)
- Make your rules as specific as possible (class or id).

Comment: Wow! This is really speedy! Thank you! Before using insertRow I have been using innerHTML for these cases but IE did not append the row, I was looking for the cause and according to Microsoft is because I can not use innerHTML on an inline element and I need to use insertRow for that case.

Comment: I further optimized by adding document.createDocumentFragment() before the loop and add the tr in the documentFragment and then add all into the table after the loop.

I also noticed that tr:nth-child(even) is very slow, so I did the same thing with javascript and CSS class.

Here is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4dpGz/3/

Answer (score 6):

if your table has regular columns (without colspan and/or rowspan) you can improve a bit the rendering time applying the `table-layout:fixed` property:

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/table-layout

> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent cell content may not fit in the column widths provided.

Comment: Thank you for responding this post, I already know about that and `table-layout:fixed` is already applied. You can see the demo in my updated post.

Answer (score 5):

Also, as in any HTML element in chrome, adding "transform: rotateX(0deg);" to the table element forces hardware acceleration to kick in, speeding up scrolling significantly (if that's the issue).

Comment: Not really :) But here's a link that does :-P [Scrolling Performance](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/)

Comment: My whole page was laggy but this simple trick solved everything.

Comment: That's super hacky... I'm impressed. Remember that not all users have hardware accelerated browsers...

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with very large tables (say, 5000 or even 500,000 rows), I recommend a tiny plugin called [Clusterize](https://clusterize.js.org/). You don't even need jQuery to use it. The idea is similar to lazy loading images, and it works extremely well in practice.

Comment: Very useful plug-in! Unfortunately paginating my table was not an option and Clusterize sped up my table dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

Tables have to be downloaded and render in full before they are displayed, appearing to take a longer to display. This lapse all depends on processing power:

[Are large html tables slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364213/are-large-html-tables-slow)

For the amount of rows you have I'm surprised you are seeing any noticeable lag, though you can try a few things from here, to help us help you out:

- remove gradient backgrounds (as they are rendered by the browser)
- paginate form data
- output form rows in chunks (say, 200 rows at a time)
- does removing all css help?
- specify a exact width + height on table rows, cells

Comment: Thank you for responding this post, I read that post before I posted here, but I think I can not paginate this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

I find that putting a large table into a div, it's best to use a setTimeout.  This seems to speed it up significantly in Chrome when storing the table in a global var first then calling the function in a setTimeout.

```
setTimeout("setTable(tdata)",1);

function setTable(d) {
        $("#myDiv").html(d);
}
```

Cheers!
B55