# Heavy HTML, slow browser decompression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very heavy report that I render in a html table. It's dynamic, sometimes it can have 100 rows times 100 columns, sometimes it can reach more than 1000 rows. 
This report also has diferrent ways to be visualized, so I use CSS to show/hide some values depending on which way I want to see it. The data in the rows is is that like a tree, so I use buttons to show/hide child rows to simulate the effect of a tree (by the default, the child rows are "closed"/display:none).

The problem is that when I get one of those large reports with 1000 rows, the browser **sometimes** (almost always on Chrome and sometimes on Firefox) takes a long while (more than 5 minutes) to decrompress the HTML (that comes from an Ajax call). The whole thing gets around 37mb decompressed, sometimes the browser manages it fast, other times it's very slow.

The only thing I could think about, was rendering parts of the diffent "views" of the report (meaning smaller junks of html), but then I would need to process the whole thing at least three times (on demand) so the user would see all possible combinations.

I only start having this problem when the hmlt is 30mb plus. I know there's something very wrong that I must be doing, but I don't know where to start most stuff I read about html perfomance doesn't seem to apply. I have no jquery bindings running on callback, so it's nothing related to that.

**Edit:**

I made some test after rendering it in smaller chunks (the large one went from 35mb to 21mb. A smaller one is now 2,4mb). But it seems it's not related to the size of the html, even the smaller one sometimes slows down (5 seconds, 3 seconds, than 30 seconds). I was wrong about that.

I'm currently using .html() to place the result of the ajax call on a div, I tried with .load() as well.

Comment: Just for giggles, try adding `table-layout: fixed;` to the CSS rules for your table if you haven't already. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8643718/1030243.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was mistaken all along. It had nothing to do with the hmlt size, nor to how the browser handles the decompression. The thing is that, the html wasn't being compressed at all.

I noticed it, when I compared the network tab on Chrome. In our development enviroment with Visual Studio and IIS Express it showed that the HTML was compressed, but in our external sandbox enviroment (where I was running data havier tests) it wasn't compressed.

I had checked our IIS before and the dynamic compression was enabled, but after some research I learned that the default compression level for dynamic requests is O, so I changed it to 4.

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much

But it still wasn't working correctly, I thought it was related to the mimeTypes enabled for the IIS compression, but it still didn't solve the problem.

Finally, I've noticed that it was woking fine at home, but at my work place it was still very slow. The reason for this seems to be the proxy for out network.

> noCompressionForProxies   Optional Boolean attribute.
>
> Specifies whether the HTTP 1.1 response is disabled for compression
> requests that come through proxy servers.
>
> Note: Some HTTP proxy servers do not handle the caching of compressed
> objects correctly. You can use this setting to avoid returning a
> compressed file to a proxy server that cannot decompress it.
>
> The default value is true.
>
> http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression

Which means, just changing the compression level already had fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can start load 100 rows, then load 100 more with Ajax, then more and more.

Actually, you can not see whole 30+ MB report at once, because the monitor size, then you can dynamically load-destroy the data. Lets stay visible just 1000 lines of the data.