# IE6 Performance issue with source code above 10k lines

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I have a big performance issue in IE6 even with javascript turned-off.
It's strange because sometimes when the page is loaded, the header is floated next to the footer, or slideshow is over the the content.

I wonder if someone had same or similiar issues in IE6 and if i minify a generated source code into a one-line, will it help somehow to gain loadspeed in that browser ?

-Want to mention that it should be compatible with ie6 so please, do not post a messages like - use modern browsers.

**The problem was in MS png fixer inside css. Even if i turned off a javascript, it still works, so when i removed css lines with ms filter for png transparency, it starts working like it should.**

Thanks for any submits.

Comment: I doubt minifying will help much. You need to get on to newer browsers.

Comment: I don't want to nag, but Microsoft provided a solution for _all_ IE6 issues in 2006.

Comment: noway, the entire web should be cross-browsed, so i have to stick with that ie6. it works fine, of caurse with big difference between modern browsers. but suddenly i recognized a new issue in ie6.

Comment: Have you run the code through the w3c validator? I would imagine a browser like IE6 is so flaky it could choke if the html source wasn't valid

Comment: It is likely *not* the *line count* but the size in general. Newlines just cause ASI in JavaScript and (possibly) add text-nodes in HTML.

Comment: @MrLister - yeah you are right, but unfortunately that is not a solution.

Comment: IE6 is depreciated. I wouldnt bother making it compatible with IE6.

Comment: @JoshuaM Thank goodness I can *finally* agree with that statement... but as of (early) last year we still had to support IE6... still stuck at IE7 now, however :(

Comment: @pst IE7 is much more friendly. IE6 was awful, IE7 was ok, IE8 went back a step, then Microsoft started caring about where other browsers were going. We charged extra for IE6 compatible sites, no one wanted one when we did that. They wanted it because they *could* have it, not cause they *needed* it.

Comment: @JoshuaM - there is no problem with IE7/8/9, only in IE6.

Comment: @aspirinemaga - I know, I wasn't saying that. I was saying it's pointless bothering with IE6.

Comment: @JoshuaM - if it depends on me, i would just put a black screen for ie6 users with white Bill Gates's signature.

Comment: The problem was in MS png fixer inside css. Even if i turned off a javascript, it still works, so when i removed css lines with ms filter for png transparency, it starts working like it should. Thanks anyway for your posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that removing newlines would increase the speed in any noticeable fashion.

That is, the performance issues are likely not caused by *line count* but rather the *size/number/type/cost* of the elements/operations *after* the parsing.

The actual [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) that handles the newlines should see them no differently in the stream than any other character. Depending on exactly what context "source" means newlines have some effect semantically at the parser:

1. CSS: none (ignoring embedded newlines)
2. HTML: possible new text-nodes or different content
3. JavaScript: automatic semicolon insertion (or embedded newlines)

However, there is no reason *not* to try a minified version quickly to see if it makes a difference and, more importantly, to satisfy your curiosity ;-) I would definitely heed the other suggestions as well, such as checking the page (everything) for validity.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what your page consists of, but my guess would be you're outputting the mother of all HTML tables?

The reason I guess that is because IE6 is known to be extremely slow when rendering large tables, particularly where the column widths are variable. (later IEs are also slow with this, but not as bad as IE6)

The reason is that the browser attempts to render the entire table before displaying anything, and performs a lot of calculations to work out how to render it.

The answers on this question may also help you: [Are large html tables slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364213/are-large-html-tables-slow)

Comment: thanks for answer, i've already met that problem with tables, but the whole website is tableless. For example, i use chrome to view source code (CTRL+U), and there are a lot of spaces between each lines, so in total it generates about 10 000 lines in source code.