# Does a CSS table (non-fixed) suffer from the same performance issues as an HTML table (non-fixed)?

Tags: html, css, performance

Pretty much as the title says, does a non-fixed table-layout share the same performance issues as that of a similar HTML table?

Comment: What do you mean by non-fixed?

Comment: And what are the performance issues you speak of? Details please.

Comment: Can't say I've had any problems with tables before but I want to look into the claims like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1364234/1059070 and how HTML tables compare to CSS ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with non-fixed tables is that to determine the width of a column, all cells of that column have to be loaded. This only matters if…

1. … you have a table with several kilobytes or megs of data
2. … you do a table layout on a large page (wrong for several reasons)

In a sense, this is similar to using CSS. However, the HTML will sometimes be displayed *before* the style is applied, so the page loads fast, but it takes roughly as long until you see the correct layout.

Unless you have a very large table, using the html table is probably always better, as it is more idiomatic. If you have to create a large table and loading time bothers you, benchmark to get that split-second difference.

So my answer to your yes/no-question is: No, unless you want to see the same table in both cases.

Note: The last time I looked at a large html table (~3000 rows, loading time ~4sec.) it started displaying before it was fully loaded. This may not be the true for older browsers