# Expensive time displaying +100.000 entries in a CSHTML Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

I've been working on my application that displays a table with entries of Cars actually on the market. As this application has to handdle with a lot of information (More than 100.000 entries), I'm having problems at displaying them into a table in CSHTML (Loading time is excesive, probably more than 10 minutes).

I'll share some code to show you how it's encoded actually:

```
public partial class Car
    {
        public string CarID { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Car.cs class and this is how it's displayed in the CSHTML table:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#carTable').DataTable(
    {
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50],
    }
);
<script>

<table id="carTable" class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CarID <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th>Brand <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th>Price<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var car in Model.CarsList)
        {
        <tr>
            <td data-sortable="true">@car.CarID</td>
            <td data-sortable="true">@car.Brand</td>
            <td data-sortable="true">@car.Price</td>
        }
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is how in my controller I add them to my ViewModel (It has only one property --> IEnumerable CarsList) :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowCars(){
    CarViewModel cVM = new CarViewModel();
    var carsInMyDB = _context.Cars.ToList();
    cVM.CarsList = carsInMyDB;
    return View(cVM)
}
```

As said previously, have to load more than 100.000 entries in this table, and it's taking too much time to show them properly.

**What suggestions/changes could I made to improve my load time?**

Thanks for your time and the answers! :D

Comment: How about paging?

Comment: And you may want to look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364213/are-large-html-tables-slow.

Answer (score 1):

[Paging](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/328/simple-paging-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages) may help.
Also, if you want all of them to be on one page, read about lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad solution:

```
_context.Cars.ToList();
```

It might work when you have few records but this fetch whole table in your memory and it is eating a lot of your server resources. Why you do not use pagination and database procedure to fetch records depending on your page size. This job is done a lot faster on database than in your code as.

You could pass page number and page limit to your database stored procedure that will do the job a lot faster.

If you use SQL Server, here is an example of such a stored procedure and its call from controller:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CarsSelect]
    (@limit INT,
     @page INT)
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pk) AS RowNum, *  
         FROM 
             Cars) AS RowConstrainedResult
    WHERE   
        RowNum >= @page * @limit 
        AND RowNum <= @page * @limit + @limit 
    ORDER BY 
        RowNum
```

And here return JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult GetCars(int page, int limit)
{
  //Your context get cars from DB with limit and page
  List<Cars> cars = _context.CarsSelect(limit, page); 
  var carsJSON = from c in cars 
  select new {
         CarID = c.CarID,
         Brand = c.Brand 
         Price = c.Price
  };      
  return Json ( new { carsJSON }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case data is getting slow...because you have used foreach to bind the data to 
  table..there is no need to use foreach just use jquery datatbles plugins..

```
 <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto">
   <table id="myDatatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Room Name</th>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th>Room Rate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

```
@section scritps{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
}

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
        "proccessing": true,
        "searching": true,
        "info": true,
        "paging":true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/Admin/Rooms',
            "type": "get",
            "datatype":"json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Room_name", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "RoomType", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "Room_rate", "autoWidth": true }
        ]

    })
})
```

```
   and this is controllers code 

    public ActionResult Rooms()
    {
        using (RoomReservationEntities db = new RoomReservationEntities())
        {
            var room_query = (from room in db.Rooms
                    join roomType in db.Room_Type
                    on room.RoomType_id equals roomType.RoomType_id
                    select new { room.Room_id, room.Room_name, roomType.RoomType, 
                                roomType.Room_rate }).ToList();

            return Json(new { data = room_query }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

you can also speed the process by using serverside pagination using Skip and Take linq 
   operators just follow the link...

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-paging-using-skip-and-take-operators-in-linq/